# Get start- enddates of periods based on periodtype

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have the following  query:

```
declare @onlyrecents2 as int = 1
declare @periodtype2 as nvarchar(15) = 'w'
declare @last_modified_date_date2 as datetime2 = '2020-1-21 14:15:52.430'
declare @last_wanted_date_date2 as datetime2 = '2020-5-21 14:15:52.430'

select
IIF(@periodtype2 = 'w', iif(datediff(week,@last_modified_date_date2, @last_wanted_date_date2)>1,1,0),
IIF(@periodtype2 = 'm', iif(datediff(month,@last_modified_date_date2, @last_wanted_date_date2)>1,1,0),
IIF(@periodtype2 = 'q', iif(datediff(quarter,@last_modified_date_date2, @last_wanted_date_date2)>1,1,0),
IIF(@periodtype2 = 'y', iif(datediff(year,@last_modified_date_date2, @last_wanted_date_date2)>1,1,0),
IIF(@periodtype2 = 'c',0,0)))))
 as loop_needed
,IIF(@periodtype2 = 'w', datediff(week,@last_modified_date_date2, @last_wanted_date_date2),
IIF(@periodtype2 = 'm', datediff(month,@last_modified_date_date2, @last_wanted_date_date2),
IIF(@periodtype2 = 'q', datediff(quarter,@last_modified_date_date2, @last_wanted_date_date2),
IIF(@periodtype2 = 'y', datediff(year,@last_modified_date_date2, @last_wanted_date_date2),
IIF(@periodtype2 = 'c',0,0)))))as nr_loops_needed
```

It  tells me that if I need the records with a modified_date between '2020-1-21 14:15:52.430' and  '2020-5-21 14:15:52.430' and I want to retrieve them per week that I need 17 loops.

Now what I would like is a query that splits the daterange between `'2020-1-21 14:15:52.430'` and  `'2020-5-21 14:15:52.430'` in 17 loops:

| loop | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-1-21 14:15:52.430 | 2020-1-28 14:15:52.430 |
| 2 | 2020-2-4 14:15:52.430 | 2020-2-11 14:15:52.430 |
| ... |  |  |
| 17 | startdate | endddate |

I know it can be done, I've done it before but for the love of God can't remember how.....

Edit: to be clear, I only  need to know how I can split the daterange from `@last_modified_date_date2`  to '@last_wanted_date_date2'  in weeks, months, quarter, years, based on the parameter `@periodtype2`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make this question much clearer.  Why are you using nested `IIF()` when `CASE` is much simpler?

Comment: Gordon, I find the IIF simpler, matter of taste I think.
What do you mean by sample data? I only need to know how I can split the daterange from '2020-1-21 14:15:52.430' to '2020-5-21 14:15:52.430'  in weeks, months, quarter, years, based on the parameter @periodtype2

Comment: . . In my opinion, there is an argument that non-standard extensions to SQL for "if" functionality are simpler than `case` -- certainly a bit less typing -- although I don't agree with that opinion.  But for nested conditional statements, I think it is clear that `case` is simpler.

Comment: What results do you expect for 20200131 to 20200331 by month? Is 20200231 a problem? Do you really want to include time-of-day rather than midnight?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I will check he CASE Statement for this case

Comment: @HABO Yes, I do need the timeportion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way by converting all the unit to days ( for example) and use  cte to loop through starting from startdate until reaching enddate:

```
DECLARE @datepart AS NVARCHAR(15) = N'year';
DECLARE @startDate AS DATETIME2 = '2020-1-21 14:15:52.430';
DECLARE @enddate AS DATETIME2 = '2020-5-21 14:15:52.430';
DECLARE @diffDays INT;

SET @diffDays = CASE @datepart
                    WHEN 'week' THEN 7
                    WHEN 'day' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'quarter' THEN 91
                    WHEN 'year' THEN 365
                    ELSE 1
                END;
WITH cte
AS
    (
        SELECT
            @startDate AS startdate
            , CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, @diffDays, @startDate) > @enddate 
                  THEN @enddate
                  ELSE DATEADD(DAY, @diffDays, @startDate)
              END      AS enddate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            cte.enddate
            , CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, @diffDays, cte.enddate) > @enddate 
                  THEN @enddate
                  ELSE DATEADD(DAY, @diffDays, cte.enddate)
              END AS enddate
        FROM
            cte
        WHERE
            cte.enddate < @enddate
    )
SELECT * FROM cte;
```